# Auto Generate entity in Entity Framework if a table is added to the schema

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

In Entity Framework, is there any way to make edmx file to automatically create entity when a table is added to the schema in the database and delete entity when a table is removed from the schema at run-time?

Comment: Short answer: no. There are no "auto-update" functions in EF - and quite frankly, I don't think those would make a lot of sense anyway.... (e.g. I **don't** want all tables to be added to my model - and which model do they get added to if I have more than one??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no EDMX file at runtime - there are only mapping files which are static XMLs. There is no mechanism controlling your database and modify these files if database changes (moreover as @marc pointed which files should be modified if you have more then one model?).

This is even doesn't make too much sense if you try to do it manually. Adding table to mapping is not enough - you also need a class and code which will use that class - both added at runtime.

There are more problems related to this. EF is tool configured at design time. The only exception is loading configuration classes for EF code first but again configuration classes are created at design time (I intentionally skip any ridiculous approaches with emitting MSIL at runtime).